# Write a program that generates a random sequence of 20 die tosses

Tags: java

I have very little experience in programming, and I am taking my first programming course in college right now.  We have a problem in class to write a program that generates a sequence of random numbers from 1 to 6 and place parentheses around series of consecutive numbers.  For example, if the sequence was 12553124322223655631, the program would print 12(55)31243(2222)36(55)631.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
package inRun;
import java.util.Random;

public class Prob612 {
    public static void main(String args []){
    Random rand = new Random();
    boolean inRun = false;
    int i = 0;

int [] values;
values = new int[20];


    while (i < values.length){
        int j = rand.nextInt(7);
        if (j > 0 && j <= 6){
            values[i] = j;
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        if (inRun){
            if (values[i] != values[i + 1]){
                System.out.print(")");
                inRun = false;
            }
        }
        if (inRun = false){
            if (values[i] == values[i - 1]){
                System.out.print("(");
                inRun = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(values[i]);
    }

    if (inRun){System.out.print(")");}
}

}
```

When I run this program, it prints the sequence, but without the parentheses.  I'm thinking that I would need to use an enhanced `for` loop, but I have no idea how I would go about doing that with a program like this.  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: `if (inRun = false)` doesn't do what you want it to. Look carefully...

Comment: I wouldn't use an enhanced for loop, since you'll likely need to know indices for this. Maintain 2 index values: a start and end that represent a stretch of consecutive values. Whenever you get the next value, check if it was the same as the previous. If it is, advance the "end" index. If it's not, add parenthesis at the start and end indices, then reset the indices to the current index.

Comment: "place parentheses around series of consecutive numbers", I don't seem to understand what you mean by this given your desired output. Do you mean repeating numbers instead?

Comment: This is going to give you an error on the lines that say: `if (values[i] != values[i + 1]){` when you get to the last element of the array. The first `if` statement isn't necessary if you use `nextInt(6) + 1`.

Comment: @px06 yes that's what I meant

Comment: You are making this way harder than it needs to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost solved it. Two things to be aware of:

- You are assigning the boolean to false inside the if statement. `(inRun = false)` should be `( inRun == false )`.
- You are overrunning the array with values[i + 1] when on the last item.

This should do it.

```
  boolean inside = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (inside) {
        if (values[i] != values[i - 1]) {
            System.out.print(')');
            inside = false;
        }

      } else {
        if (i < values.length - 1) {
            if (values[i + 1] == values[i]) {
                System.out.print('(');
                inside = true;
            }
        }
      }
      System.out.print(values[i]);
  }
```

Comment: The inside boolean statement is not necessary

Comment: @Bijay Gurung thank you this worked perfectly.  I just want to clarify the last statement.  You said before that the program was overrunning the array, so is that why you made a special case to print the last digit?

Comment: This fails if you have a matching pair at the end... output: 2(66)414(3333)1523615(664)

Comment: @derek00101110 Yes. That was the idea but as pointed out by Nicole, it failed when there was a running sequence just before the last item. I have edited it now.

Comment: @NicolePhillips Thank you for pointing out the failing case. As for the boolean, I couldn't figure out how we can do it without using it. (?)

Answer (score 0):

I give you another solution without using a boolean, but using two for cycles to find the matching consecutive numbers. Comments should explaine the code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        // store the number of consecutive numbers
        int count = 0;

        /* check if it's not the last element (avoid outOfBound Exception when you reach the last element)
           and if there is a match */

        if(i+1 < values.length && values[i] == values[i+1])
        {
            count++;

            //print parenthesis and the first matching number
            System.out.print("("+values[i]);

            // use a second for to match all the possible consecutive equal numbers
            for(int j = i+1; j < values.length; j++)
            {
               // same as before, check if it's not the last element and if there is a match
                if(j+1 < values.length && values[j] == values[j+1])
                {
                    count++;
                    System.out.print(values[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                   // if you have a different value in the next array cell, then print value and close the match
                   System.out.print(values[j]+")");
                   /* assing to i the value of i + the number of matching consecutive numbers 
                     to resume the first for from the next value after the series of consecutive numbers */
                   i = i + count;
                   // exit to avoid unnecessary loops
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
        // print if you have a single number
        else
            System.out.print(values[i]);
  }
```